# Has Japan stopped producing anime based on western stories?

Tags: anime-production

I did some research to see if there exists an anime that was based on western stories and I have found [some here](http://letsanime.blogspot.com/2009/09/under-western-influence.html) (including the only one I can remember, [Cinderella Monogatari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinderella_Monogatari)). I have noticed that all anime there were old, thus, making me wonder if Japan totally stopped creating anime that are based on western stories.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No**. There are a number of recent Japanese anime based on Western stories. Some examples:

- [Gankutsuou: The Count of Monte Cristo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gankutsuou%3a_The_Count_of_Monte_Cristo) based on Alexandre Dumas, père's classic French novel, Le Comte de Monte-Cristo, aired in 2004-5.
- [Romeo × Juliet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romeo_x_Juliet) loosely based on William Shakespeare's classical play, Romeo and Juliet, along with numerous references and characters from other Shakespearean plays aired in 2007.
- [Miyuki-chan in Wonderland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miyuki-chan_in_Wonderland) is an erotic, lesbian rendition of Lewis Carroll's Alice's Adventures in Wonderland, aired in 1995.
- [Powerpuff Girls Z](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerpuff_girls_z) is a magical girl anime series based on the American animated television series The Powerpuff Girls, aired in 2006-7.
- [Deltora Quest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltora_Quest_%28anime%29) based on the series of children's books of the same name, written by Australian author Emily Rodda, aired in 2007-8.

Comment: There might be plenty more. I will update the answer with more examples if/when I find them. :)

Comment: There was also a bunch of collaborations recently between Marvel Comics and Madhouse: Wolverine, Blade, X-men, and Iron Man. Also a DC Comics collaboration with several different studios that produced the anthology Batman Gotham Knight. Oh, and Witchblade.

Comment: Many Ghibli movies are based on Western stories. Recent ones include _Arrietty_, _Tales from Earthsea_, and _Howl's moving castle_.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai Lets not forget [Gankutsuou: The Count of Monte Cristo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gankutsuou:_The_Count_of_Monte_Cristo), a free adaptation of Dumas' *Count of Monte Christo*. Also [Heidi, Girl of the Alps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heidi,_Girl_of_the_Alps), adapted from the Johan Spyri novel. [Future Boy Conan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_Boy_Conan), based on *The Incredible Tide* by Alexander Key. [Time Jam: Valerian & Laureline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Jam:_Valerian_%26_Laureline), a French/Japanese co-production, based on a long running French comic.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai Also, you should include [Oyayubihime Monotgatari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumbelina:_A_Magical_Story) (based on *Thumbelina*), which the OP mentioned, and [Trapp Family Story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapp_Family_Story) (based on the novel *The Story of the Trapp Family Singers* which inspired *The Sound of Music*)

Comment: I don't think this answer needs to contain every single recent example... I think it's sufficient as is, and adding more examples would be pedantic.

Comment: @atlantiza I did say I would update the answer *if/when I find them*, but I did not say anything about whether I would *try* to find them. he he he. ;)

Comment: @Deidara-senpai Yes, but if you list a lot, there isn't much added value. I'd rather see 5 good examples instead of all 100 examples.

Comment: @atlantiza I know what you mean. I wasn't planning to even *try* to find any more examples. As per my first comment, I only have to update the answer *if* I find any more examples. If I don't even try, there is nothing more to do.

Comment: I think the question was already answered (since it was answerable with either yes or no, and by some examples to prove the answer) so there's no need to update or add more examples. :)

Comment: I just said I would update with more examples, but I never intended to do it. Ah, never mind, no sense of humor here.

Answer (score 2):

At least, there's the [World Masterpiece Theater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Masterpiece_Theater). Between 1969 and 1997, and 2007-2009, they produced anime based on a classic book or story, also western. I can't find anything that tells me whether it's over.

Besides from that, I don't know any anime based on western stories.

Comment: Haven't heard any latest anime based from a western story as well. Maybe they have stopped, though not officially.

Comment: @xjshiya: That's what I'm thinking as well.